# Eclipse IDE can't open

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse-Photon IDE can't open. showing the message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmoza.jpg)
In my machine java version "1.8.0_391" installed.

Comment: Your image is too small to read clearly. What is the error message? Have you reported this to TestNG? What release did you update to from Eclipse Photon?

Comment: Photon to 2023-09, suggestion upon hover "Create annotation 'BeforeTest' and 'Fix Project Setup'" No I didn't report to TestNG.

Comment: Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13

Comment: Exit Code 13 is quite common, and a common question. The most common causes are that your Java runtime is itself broken in some way, your copy of Eclipse is 64-bit while your Java is 32-bit, or vice-versa. 2023-09 requires Java 17, so even if you don't have a 32/64-bit mismatch, you need a newer runtime than Java 8. Which of these scenarios matches yours?

Of course, most of the downloads from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ *include* a Java Runtime so you can unpack the download and just run it. Then you'd be completely up to date.